# Closed form for number of tuple $(a,b,c)$ with $ab=c$, with integers $a,b,c\in[1,n]$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Somewhere I encountered this equality.

> The number of tuples $(a,b,c)$ where integers $a,b,c\in [1,n]$ such that $ab=c$ is equal to $$2\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}\Big(\left\lfloor\frac ni\right\rfloor-i\Big)+\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$$

I tried to reduce this problem and observed that the number of such tuples is equal to the number of lattice points in the 1st quadrant under and on the hyperbola $xy=n$, excluding the points on the axes. Though it doesn't help me to solve the problem. Can anyone help to prove this, preferably using my observation or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such tuples with $a<b$, we need $a^2<ab\le n$, hence $$\tag1a<\sqrt n$$ and $b\le \frac na$. 
 However, our assumption $b>a$ strikes of the first $a$ of the possible values $1,2,\ldots, \lfloor\frac na\rfloor$ for $b$, i.e., there are only $$\tag2\left\lfloor \frac na\right\rfloor -a$$ possible values for $b$. Of course, each such choice of $a$ and $b$ leads to a unique $c$ and ultimately a valid triple.
So if we let $a$ run over all integers $\ge1$ and $<\sqrt n$, we count
$$ \sum_{a=1}^{\lceil\sqrt n\rceil -1}\left(\left\lfloor \frac na\right\rfloor -a\right)$$
triples with $a<b$. By symmetry, we count the same number of triples with $a>b$. Finally, we count $\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$ triples with $a=b$ (and hence $c$ any perfect square $\le n$). This leads us to a 
$$\tag3 2\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil\sqrt n\rceil -1}\left(\left\lfloor \frac ni\right\rfloor -i\right)+\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor.$$
The difference to the desired formula is that the summation limit  $\lceil\sqrt n\rceil-1$ may differ from $\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$. However, this is only possible if $n$ is a perfect square, say $n=m^2$,  and in that case $\lceil\sqrt n\rceil-1=m-1=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor \;-1$, i.e., $(3)$ contains an additional summand for $i=m$. But as $\left\lfloor \frac nm\right\rfloor-m=0$, this additional summand does not matter and we conclude that $(3)$ can also be written as 
$$\tag4 2\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}\left(\left\lfloor \frac ni\right\rfloor -i\right)+\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor.$$